# Error while using Ternary operator with int and boolean

Tags: java, ternary

Can you please help me understand where i m doing the mistake. 
I cam across this question while doing the beginner java material.

Ques: - Show how this sequence can be rewritten using the ? operator
if(x < 0) y = 10; else y = 20;

Ans: - x < 0 ? y =10 : y =20;

But when i tried performing the same i am getting an error

```
public class Ternary {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result, x, y;
    result = x < 0 ? y =10 : y =20;
    System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Error at result:- Multiple markers at this line
    - Incompatible conditional operand types int and 
     boolean
    - Syntax error on token "=", != expected

Comment: What is the purpose of `y` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a ternary operator you're assigning the left most variable to the result of the condition. In other words you only need two variables (I'll use result and x).

So the code should be:

result = x < 0 ? 10 : 20;

This will set result = 10 if x < 0 else result will be 20!

Comment: More like `y = x < 0? 10 : 20;` and just get rid of `result`, if you want it to match the question.

Comment: I considered that but "result" was being printed...its a better "match" for the question!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code like this. It will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result, y;
    int x = -1;
    // Next try with int x = 1;
    result = x < 0 ? (y = 10) : (y = 20);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```